# HKDevice with empty localIdentifier and UDIDeviceIdentifier

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, healthkit

Using the healthKit framework, I tried to read steps count of my iPhone and Apple watch in the health app. But when i queried `HKQuantitySample` `HKDevice` object, it did not show the `localIdentifier` and `UDIDeviceIdentifier`. 
Any idea why they were empty? 
Was it due to the sources not recording the info?

The request

```
func getFitness() {
    let stepsCount = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(
        HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)

    let stepsSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: stepsCount!,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 10000,
        sortDescriptors: nil)  { 
          (query, results, error) in
            if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
                for result in results {
                    print("device: \(result.device) steps:\(result)" )
                }
            }
    }

    self.healthStore?.executeQuery(stepsSampleQuery)
}
```

The response

```
device: <<HKDevice: 0x14e238380>, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone7,1, software:9.2.1> steps:63 count "iPhone6plus" (9.2.1) "iPhone" 2016-03-31 09:11:13 +0800 2016-03-31 09:11:58 +0800

device: <<HKDevice: 0x14e2385a0>, name:Apple Watch, manufacturer:Apple, model:Watch, hardware:Watch1,1, software:2.1> steps:15 count "Apple Watch" (2.1) "Apple Watch" 2016-03-31 11:15:23 +0800 2016-03-31 11:15:31 +0800
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The `localIdentifier` and `UDIDeviceIdentifier` are not recorded by HealthKit for iPhone and Apple Watch sources.